# How to call a function of 1 controller in another in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a function in `commonservice` and i want to call the function by sending the type as argument from another controller and how can i do that,

**commonservice :**

```
function getCommonLookupData(type) {
                    var data = angular.fromJson(EmployeeRoles.getItem('lookupData'));
                    var arr = [];
                    if (data)
                        arr = data[type];
                    var arr1 = [];
                    if (arr) {
                        $.each(arr, function (index, val) {
                            arr1.push(val);
                        });
                    }
                    return arr;
                }
            }
```

**contrlrm :**

```
commonService.getCommonLookupData(EmployeeRoles);
```

and how can i get the arr of the function,can anyone help please.Thanks.

Comment: i cannot understand, do you want to call service function from different controllers ?

Answer (score 1):

You should inject the service in the controller like

```
     app.controller('MyController',function($scope,myServiceName){
         myServiceName.myServiceFunction();
      });
```